# Flutter - How to make a stack of slidable card

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to make a stack of slidable cards  like this in flutter.

There must be both right and left sliding possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For swiping a stack of cards you can use [swipable_stack](https://pub.dev/packages/swipable_stack) package. There is also [this GitHub code](https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/master/animations/lib/src/misc/card_swipe.dart) to get some ideas in case you want to implement it by yourself not using a package.